# WCF - Self hosted or IIS Preference?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I am relatively green with C# and WCF. I have landed on a project where I am creating self hosted WCF services running as Windows services but am starting to wonder if I should use IIS instead (which we don't currently use) as managing all of these services could eventually get cumbersome.

Despite my best efforts, I have yet to find any definitive information about why I might favor one approach over the other. The services are primarily used for utility stuff like resizing images, retrieving files, etc. and are called by both C# and Java clients.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest answer would be 'it depends'. On your requirements. You can self host without problems, but IIS will manage resources more effectively and enable you to fine tune stuff more easily than self-hosted.

For instance, in IIS would be more simple to deploy a new version or remove and old one.

Comment: ... and it would be way more easier to think about Recycling, Shutdown of the w3wp - true, isn't it :)

Comment: On the other hand: (1) you possibly have to deal with IIS outages and app pool recycling, and (2) IIS will spin up the `ServiceHost` when the first request comes in -> that takes some time, which you don't incur when self-hosting (since you yourself are creating and opening the `ServiceHost` and keep it up and running)

Comment: @marc_s, true, I haven't thought of this when answering. But the perf. hit will be only during the first request.

Comment: @BrunoBrant: the first request after every time IIS decides to discard your `ServiceHost` - that can happen several times an hour, depending on traffic for your service.

Comment: @marc_s, indeed. So that's the trade-off, anyway: self host enables you to keep all the services in memory. Which *can* mean wasting memory with something you're not using. In any case, I wrote a small program to check the memory consumption for each service using self hosting. It was pretty small on my machine, resulting in about 102.000 bytes for every service. I never executed them though. And, of course, your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have experienced difficulties with large streams and hosting in IIS, where the exact same code runs great in a self-hosted service but chokes somewhat non-deterministically with (spurious?) OutOfMemoryExceptions when hosted in IIS.

Comment: @DanFitch, I would love to learn more about this situation. I'd imagine that IIS would do a better job at managing resources than a simple self hosted console thing. Maybe some configuration behaving unexpectedly?

Comment: I think the problem I had is actually quite rare, but I just wanted to say something in case of future Googlers. I suspect it may have something to do with how the IIS hosting machinery impacts the garbage collection during the streaming operation. I tried a lot of different `Web.config` tweaks, on both the httpRuntime/system.web stuff *and* the WCF binding attributes, but none of them affected the problem.

Comment: Update on this: There was some bizarre interplay between the .NET `SqlFileStream` object and its transaction and the way IIS dealt with the transaction or IO locks or SOMETHING. Once the code was changed to not use the base `SqlFileStream`, and we rolled our own stream class, it ran fine inside IIS and inside a raw WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine.

Generally, using the builtin IIS hosting capabilities can make deployment and configuration simpler for you.  Also you have the activation model of http.sys - which means IIS will start the necessary process for you when an appropriate message arrives.

Clients of any platform can connect to the WCF services regardless whether they are self-hosted or IIS hosted.

ps: [how to allow IIS-hosted WCF services to store their configuration data in distinct xxx.config files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/22/custom-service-config-file-for-a-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis.aspx?Redirected=true)

Comment: and you are bound to the IIS as your host - all the problems with recycling, shutdown, ... as long as you do not use your wcf-service as a data-store which reads a huge dataset on startup, that'd be fine ...